# Vue js v-repeat not showing anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js, repeat

I am totally new to `vue.js`. I am trying to repeat a simple list but its not showing anything. My code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VUE Series</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="tasks">
                <div>
                    <h2>Tasks</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li v-repeat="tasks"> {{ $value }} </li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `app.js` file is :

```
new Vue({
    el : '#tasks',

    data : {
        tasks : ['Assam', 'Manipur', 'Meghalaya']
    }
})
```

Fiddle link is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/98xphaez/)

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the official docs instead of older tutorials you find online.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `v-for` instead of `v-repeat` and the syntax should be `v-for="task in tasks"`and you use `task`to reference the current task.